# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILEでcsvをデータベースにインサートできない

Tags: php, mysql

初めて投稿致します。

プログミングを初めてまだ3ヶ月弱のため、質問仕方等に至らない点等御座いますが、 
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

---

### 実現したいこと

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILEを用いて、phpからcsvをデータベースにインサートしたい

---

### 問題点

下記、コードで実行すると、エラーが発生する

```
        try{

      $this->_kpi_pdo =new PDO(DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
      $this->_kpi_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $this->_kpi_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
      $this->_kpi_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES UTF8");
      $this->_kpi_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
      $this->_kpi_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE, true);


    }catch(PDOException $Exception){

      die('エラー:'.$Exception->getMessage());

    }



try{

      $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE"." '".DOWNLOAD_FILE_PATH.”ファイル名.csv"."'"." INTO TABLE order_sales_aggregate FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ";
      $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $Exception){

    die('エラー:'.$Exception->getMessage());

    }
```

<エラー>

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

---

色々なサイトを見て試して見ましたが、改善することができません。

ご検討のほど何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: ファイルの読み込みのエラーとは違うようなので質問時のタイポかとは思いますが…、PDOのオブジェクトの宣言と`prepare`部分のオブジェクトが合っていなかったり、文字列のくくりがおかしいです。一度、確認してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとう御座います。申し訳御座いません。確認したところ、質問時のタイピングミスでした。しかしながら、ミスを修正してもやはり上記エラーが発生致します。